# How to get node of which keyframe was added?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a custom `Animation` node like this:

Custom_AnimationPlayer:

```
tool
extends AnimationPlayer

func add_animation(name : String, animation: Animation):
    var ani = Custom_Animation.new()
    .add_animation(name, ani)
```

Custom_Animation:

```
tool
extends Animation
class_name Custom_Animation

var local_node=self.get_local_scene()

func track_insert_key(track_idx : int, time : float, key, transition : float = 1) -> void:
    
    var key_idx=track_find_key(track_idx,time,true)
    
    .track_insert_key(track_idx, time, key, transition)
    
    var track_path=track_get_path(track_idx)
    var key_node=local_node.get_node(track_path)
    
    # use key_node
```

I'm trying to get the node of which the key was added (`key_node`) but this only works if the `AnimationPlayer`'s `Root Node` is the top most node

so is there any reliable way to get the node of which the keyframe was added?

Comment: The `Animation` resource *should* emit a `"changed"` signal. It *should*, but last time I checked it didn't do it.

Comment: @Theraot nvm I added my own custom signal